# Error in levels(test$Variable1) = levels(train$Variable1) : attempt to set an attribute on NULL

Tags: r

```
levels(train$Variable1)
```

While running the above line, it executes well and shows me the result.

```
levels(test$Variable1) = levels(train$Variable1)
```

But trying to assign the output like the one shown above results in the below error. Looking for help to understand why it's happening and overcome it. Btw it's a factor variable.

*Error in levels(test$Variable1) = levels(train$Variable1) :    attempt to set an attribute on NULL*

Comment: to change a factor's levels, use `var <- factor(var,levels=levels(other_var))`

Comment: generally speaking it is a good idea to figure out all your data transformation issues before you split the data into test and train.

Comment: @scoa - test$Variable1 <- factor(test$Variable1, levels=levels(train$Variable1) is throwing up error. Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Variable1", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 3